# Symfony Render Controller _fragment ResourceNotFound

Tags: php, symfony

Hey webworker out there,

i have a mysterious Symfony error.

```
{{ render(controller('Bundle:Action')) }}
```

throws (Stack Trace Plain Text)

> [1] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the
>   rendering of a template ("") in "::base.html.twig" at line 46. at n/a
>   in /Users/christian/Web/SECRET/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4730
>
> [2] Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: at
>   n/a in /Users/christian/Web/SECRET/app/cache/dev/appDevUrlMatcher.php
>   line 4163
>
> at appDevUrlMatcher->match('/_fragment')
>       in /Users/christian/Web/SECRET/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1419

**In appDevUrlMatcher i can`t find any "_fragment", ResourceNotFoundException is thrown, render(controller throws Twig_Error_Runtime**

Every Render Controller i create throws exactly this Error.

I have no Idea what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the right bundle namespace, the controller and the right action

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles', { 'max': 3 })) }}
</div>
```

- **AcmeArticleBundle**: is the bundle
- **Article**: is the controller
- **recentArticles**: is the action

Comment: Bundle:Action was an Example.
{{ render(controller("FrameworkBundle:Template:template")) <= same error

Comment: You must check the route of the action and the existence of the template.Also try to clear the caches

Comment: The Route? There is no route

Cache is cleared soooo often.

`{{ render(controller("FrameworkBundle:Template:template"))` is build in, why does it crash, i dont understand. Error Message "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("")" is so stupid too

Comment: everything is working fine, only render controller, thats not, render url works fine also